# Can i select the second link inside my navigation link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a sharepoint 2013 site, and I want to force my second link inside the Quick Edit link (left side navigation) to always be Blue & Bold. currently the markup looks as follow:-

[image]

so i want the "test new project er" link to always appear as Blue & bold .so can this be achieved? of course on other sites the site name will be different, but will always be placed second. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this exact markup, I'd say :

```
#zz15_RootAspMenu li:nth-child(2) a {
    color : blue;
    font-weight : bold;
}
```

Comment: now this have worked for the site home page only,, but on the subsites the css did not have any effect. although the markup i provide is from a sub-site

Comment: maybe the find a clue what might be causing this problem is that there are multiple layers on links so your css will apply on many link.. so can i force it to run on the first match only ?

Comment: now i try to define it `#zz15_RootAspMenu li:nth-child(2) a:first-of-type {
    color : blue;
    font-weight : bold;
}` but till i can see that multiple links are being set as blue & bold